# Is projection on a convex closed weakly-sequentially continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I think to have proved the following:

Given $K$ a convex closed(maybe also limited is needed)subset(also curve not just subspaces) of an Hilbert space $H$, is well defined the projection operator $p_K:H \to K$. This operator is continuos for the norm topology. If i didn't miss something, my guess (is not a very formal proof) shows that is sequentially continuous for the weak topology. Is that true?

My guess goes more or less like this: i write my convex set as intersection of half spaces, and i reduce in some way to those.

Before to try to work it out more clearly i'd like to know if anybody knows if the result is actually true.
Thanks

Comment: I may be misinterpreting what you're saying, but: A linear map $T:X\rightarrow Y$ between the normed linear spaces $X$ and $Y$ is norm-to-norm continuous if and only if $T$ is weak-to-weak continuous. This is a basic fact that you should be able to find in any Functional Analysis text. [Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA233&dq=norm+continuous+implies+weakly+continuous&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mJqXU728E8qSyAT2noCgBQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=norm%20continuous%20implies%20weakly%20continuous&f=false)  is one proof.

Comment: $P_{K}$ isn't generally linear unless $K$ is a subspace.

Comment: @David Mitra: yes as T.A.E points out projection isn't a linear map in general if K is not a subspace. But indeed my idea of considering half spaces was done in order to "linearize" as most as possible the problem, and reducing to a linear case, where as you said the proof is straightforward

Comment: I believe, there is a counter example in the paper 'Zarantonello, Eduardo H.
Projections on convex sets in Hilbert space and spectral theory. I. Projections on convex sets. Contributions to nonlinear functional analysis (Proc. Sympos., Math. Res. Center, Univ. Wisconsin, Madison, Wis., 1971), pp. 237–341. Academic Press, New York, 1971.' However, I do not have access to it, right now. The review on mathscinet also suggests the existence of a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a counter-example regarding continuity of the projection in the weak topology. Is is taken from Zarantonello's article I mentioned in the comments.

Let $H=l^2$, $K$ be the closed unit ball. Let $e_k=(0,\dots, 0,1,0,\dots)$ be the $k$-the unit element.
Set
$$
x_n := e_1 + e_n.
$$
Then $x_n\rightharpoonup e_1$. The projection of $x_n$ satisfies
$$
p_K(x_n) = \frac1{\sqrt 2}(e_1 + e_n) \rightharpoonup \frac1{\sqrt 2}e_1.
$$
Thus the projection of the weak limit of $x_n$ is $e_1$, and it is different from the weak limit of the projections, which is $\frac1{\sqrt 2}e_1$. And $p_K$ is not continuous with respect to the weak topology.